# I want to change Godaddy server from UNIX to TCP

Tags: mysql, sockets, unix, phpmyadmin, localhost

I am using windows and I want to upload mysql php project from localhost to Godaddy hosting.
When I open Godaddy phpmyadmin, database server looks like.
"Server: Localhost via UNIX socket"
I want to change UNIX socket to "TCP/IP".
Because, when I upload it from windows, the connection is not establishing.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL connections from a client (for example phpmyadmin) to the MySQL Server can use either a "UNIX socket" or TCP/IP.

The UNIX socket interface is faster than TCP/IP, but it only works if the client is on the same host as the MySQL Server.

TCP/IP is necessary for client/server connections, i.e. if the client is on a different host than the MySQL Server.

MySQL has a special way of invoking the UNIX socket interface: if the client specifies the host as the literal word "localhost" this automatically invokes the UNIX socket. It's a little bit confusing because to other clients, "localhost" means the IP address 127.0.0.1, or the loopback TCP/IP address.

So for MySQL clients, you need to make clients connect to "127.0.0.1" which ensures it will use the TCP/IP interface, even when connecting to the MySQL Server on the same host.

For phpmyadmin, you would need to edit its configuration files. See https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#server-connection-settings

You will change `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']` to "127.0.0.1" to make it use TCP/IP.

Comment: Can you explain me how we get $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']? I mean I don't know where are Mysql files in Godaddy cpanel are located. In xampp Mysql files are on Mysql folder and there have my.ini file but I don't know about Godaddy...

Comment: I linked to the documentation of phpmyadmin, I suggest you go read it if you want to learn how to administer phpmyadmin. But I assume you probably cannot change the configuration of a hosted instance of phpmyadmin. You should talk to godaddy support about that.